# Вычислить сумму ряда в Prolog

Tags: prolog, ряды, swi-prolog

Программа должна спрашивать в пользователя: N - количество членов ряда, X - значение переменной.

Вычислить сумму ряда с заданной точностью.

Все что удалось сделать, так это посчитать факториал и степень по отдельности.

```
factorial(1,1):-!.
factorial(N,F):-N1 is N-1, factorial(N1,F1), F is F1*N.

pow(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X**Y.
```

[image: Ряд]

Програмный код пишу в среде https://swish.swi-prolog.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат приведен ниже:

```
factorial(0,1) :- !.
factorial(N,F) :- N1 is N-1, factorial(N1,F1), F is F1*N.

fun(N, X, S) :-
    N = 1,
    S is (X^(N-1)),
    !.

fun(N, X, S) :-
    N1 is N - 1,
    fun(N1, X, S1),
    factorial((N-1),F),
    S is S1 + (-1^(N-1))*(X*(N-1)/F).
```